# mysql - group by indexed columns + where by indexed column caused speed decrease

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, innodb

I have table `statistics` with next structure:

```
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at        | datetime             | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| year_in_tz        | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| month_in_tz       | tinyint(3) unsigned  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

With keys on created_at, year_in_tz, month_in_tz and on (year_in_tz, month_in_tz):

```
 ALTER TABLE `statistics` ADD INDEX created_at (created_at);
 alter table statistics add index year_in_tz (year_in_tz);
 alter table statistics add index month_in_tz (month_in_tz);
 alter table statistics add index year_month_in_tz(year_in_tz,month_in_tz);
```

Some queries example...

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, year_in_tz, month_in_tz 
       FROM `statistics` 
       GROUP BY year_in_tz, month_in_tz;
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| count_all | year_in_tz | month_in_tz |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|    467890 |       2011 |          11 |
|   7339389 |       2011 |          12 |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (5.04 sec)  

mysql> describe SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, year_in_tz, month_in_tz FROM `statistics` GROUP BY year_in_tz, month_in_tz;
 +----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
 | id | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys | key              | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
 +----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | statistics         | index | NULL          | year_month_in_tz | 5       | NULL | 7797984 | Using index |
 +----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
 1 row in set (0.01 sec)

 mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, year_in_tz, month_in_tz 
        FROM `statistics` 
        WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2011-10-31 20:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 19:59:59') 
        GROUP BY year_in_tz, month_in_tz;
 +-----------+------------+-------------+
 | count_all | year_in_tz | month_in_tz |
 +-----------+------------+-------------+
 |    467890 |       2011 |          11 |
 |   7339389 |       2011 |          12 |
 +-----------+------------+-------------+
 2 rows in set (1 min 33.46 sec)

 mysql> describe SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, year_in_tz, month_in_tz FROM `statistics` WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2011-10-31 20:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 19:59:59') GROUP BY year_in_tz, month_in_tz;
 +----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
 | id | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys | key              | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
 +----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | statistics         | index | created_at    | year_month_in_tz | 5       | NULL | 7797984 | Using where |
 +----+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
 1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```

So if I use where statement with clause on indexed column + group by indexed columns, speed is extremely low. 
Maybe someone know how to improve last query to make it *faster*?

**P.S.** After playing with indexes, I found that new index on (created_at, year_in_tz, month_in_tz) made query run faster, but I want 0-1 seconds per query, not 10 seconds:

```
alter table lending_statistics add index created_at_with_year_and_month_in_tz (created_at,year_in_tz,month_in_tz);

mysql> describe SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, year_in_tz, month_in_tz FROM `statistics`        WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2011-10-31 20:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 19:59:59') GROUP BY year_in_tz, month_in_tz;
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys                                   | key                                  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | statistics         | range | created_at,created_at_with_year_and_month_in_tz | created_at_with_year_and_month_in_tz | 9       | NULL | 3612208 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

1 row in set (0.05 sec)

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all,        year_in_tz, month_in_tz        FROM `lending_statistics`        WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2011-10-31 20:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 19:59:59')        GROUP BY year_in_tz, month_in_tz;
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| count_all | year_in_tz | month_in_tz |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|    467890 |       2011 |          11 |
|   7339389 |       2011 |          12 |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (10.62 sec)
```

Comment: Just curious; since the year_in_Tz will be the same in your example, what happens if you omit it from the group by as per [article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

Comment: xQbert, nothing happens, but thanks for good idea on query optimization (omitting year_in_tz from group if range for selection is in one year).

Comment: It was just a thought based on this from the above article: You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group."  I'm at as much of a loss as you are currently

Comment: just changed last describe to right one... last was for another query.

Comment: Could you list the definition of the keys you created?

Comment: Louis-Philippe Huberdeau, added code that I used for indexes creation.

Answer (score 1):

Add the field ID to your index created_at_with_year_and_month_in_tz and then change your select statement to use

```
select count(id) ....
```

In MySQL 5.6 the ICP feature might help in this case cause all fields accessed are part of the index. I believe that MySQL might reads the actual data record when you specify count(*) hence it needs to read the index file as well as the datafile.

Comment: Tried. There are some performance improvement (up to 20%), but I do not know is this caused by adding id to index or because of current hardware state. Anyway, count(id) and count(*) using this index take same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, there is a [known MySQL issue](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52849) with datetime indexes

```
    WHERE
        created_at BETWEEN 
               CAST('2011-10-31 20:00:00' AS datetime) AND 
               CAST('2011-12-31 19:59:59'  AS datetime)
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but i do not see any changes in query performance :(

Answer (score 0):

Slow `COUNT(*)` queries is the often trouble of MySQL & PostgreSQL (and other RDBMS), because sequental table scan is performed during the query execution. Try to think about caching your aggregated data somewhere else: [memcached](http://memcached.org), [redis](http://redis.io), etc.

Comment: I'm thinking about caching statistic's compilation in another table, but it's not so fast to implement this, so I need some ideas for make current queries as fast as possible.